# Dependency path between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In our system all the data movement are done by strored procedures There are lot of legacy tables and procs and really hard to find how data is transforemd from one table to other one. 
So the process is 
Table1 -> Stored proc 1 transfroms it to -> Table 2 -> Stored proc 2 transfroms it to Table 3 etc

I know that the dependecies can be read from some system tables

```
Select Distinct
SysObjects.Name 'Table Name',
Procedures.Name 'Stored Procedure'
From SysObjects
Join (SysObjects Procedures
Join SysDepends
on Procedures.Id = SysDepends.Id)
On SysDepends.DepId = SysObjects.Id
Where SysObjects.XType = 'U'
And Procedures.XType = 'P'
Group by SysObjects.Name,
SysObjects.Id,
Procedures.Name
Order by SysObjects.Name Asc
```

Is there any analytical function in MS SQL to find the possible paths between two tables?

I am using MS 2008R2
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names of the tables, you can search the SP definition for their names.

```
SELECT name from sysobjects 
where Xtype='p' and OBJECT_DEFINITION(id) like '%tablename%'
```

Comment: ok, but I need the full path - there can be more than one intermediator stored procs and tables